# Android HttpClient indentified in PHP

Tags: php, android, apache, post

I'm using `HttpClient`, `HttpPost` and some others from `org.apache` library in Android to make some post request. Is there any way that PHP will know this request comes from an Android device? like headers or something.

Comment: you can set a fake User-Agent if you want to hide your identity

Comment: I actually wanted to verify if the request was sent from a previous version (so I can't add code to it, just work with what I have)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are try to call a PHP api and you are expecting that API to behave in a specific way for android devices .

Yes you can detect in the $_SERVER array in PHP like

```
<?php

    $ua = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    if(stripos($ua,'android') !== false) { 
          // Do some thing here which you need to do only for android device 
    }

?>
```